# Get and Post methods not working in Web API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a POST method in my controller that works fine. I want to include one more method in the same controller to get the list of records. I am unable to get the records. If I write the GET method in a different controller it works fine but when I include the same method in an existing controller it gives an error 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)'. Here is the code of my controller:

```
using MyApp.Entity.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
namespace MyApp.Server.Controllers
{
[RoutePrefix("api/dashboard")]
    public class MembersController : BaseAppController
    {
        public MembersController()
        {
        }
        public MembersController(HttpContext current)
        {
            HttpContext.Current = current;
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public string PostMemberDetails(JObject memberData)
        {
        //My code here
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public List<MyApp.Entity.Models.registeredmembers> Get(bool isRegistered)
        {
        //My code here
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the route config code:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried specifying `[HttpGet]` attribute to the get method?

Comment: Yes. I have tried that too.

Comment: Can you share what your request url is for which you are seeing this issue? I suspect you have some actions defined in your base controller which when combined with your derived controller's actions is causing an issue with routing.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the Post method to "Post" and both methods should work.

If not configured otherwise, WebApi should have actions named with method types named as Get/Post etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your route doesn't seem to allow for the `isRegistered` parameter and expects an `id` parameter instead.

Try changing the routing code to:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{isRegistered}",
    defaults: new { isRegistered = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: In my controller's method I changed Get(bool isRegistered) to Get(int id), but same result.